# Use of contradiction statement

Tags: coq

I have two natural numbers a & b. Relation between these numbers exist in the form of hypothesis (H1 H2 H3). I want to extract contradiction from these hypothesis on the basis of which I can close any sub goal.

```
H1: a<=b
H2: a>=b
H3: a=b.
```

Comment: These hypotheses are not contradictory. They are satisfied, for instance, for `a = b = 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis are not contradicting: `a=b` is an obvious solution. Assuming your hypothesis are contradicting, the `lia` tactic does the job. It can solve any goal on linear integer arithmetic in Z and nat. If you have hypothesis which contradict based on linear integer arithmetic, `lia` will solve any goal, as in:

```
Require Import Lia.

Goal forall a b : nat, a<=b -> a>=b -> a<>b -> False.
lia.
```